# Expanding this polynomial with a given power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there possibly a more simple way to expand this?:

$(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)^{10}$.

Would you be able to use the binomial theorem?

Comment: One can use the Binomial Theorem repeatedly. A whole lot of not fun. One can also use the Multinomial Theorem. Better, but still not pleasant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, typically the binomial theorem applies to binomials: "nomials" of the form $\;(x + y)^n\;$, with the "bi" in "binomial" meaning the sum of two arguments raised to a power. There is a very belabored means of using the binomial theorem by applying it repeatedly, but you might want to consider the following:

What you've got is a "multinomial".

See the [**Multinomial Theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) for some guidance. (It still involves a lot of work, though!)

From Wikipedia:

> For any positive integer m and any nonnegative integer n, the multinomial formula tells us how a sum with m terms expands when raised to an arbitrary power n:
>
> $$(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m)^n = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n} {n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} \prod_{1\le t\le m}x_{t}^{k_{t}}$$
>
> where
>
> $${n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} = \frac{n!}{k_1!\, k_2! \cdots k_m!}$$
>
> is a multinomial coefficient. The sum is taken over all combinations of nonnegative integer indices $k_1$ through $k_m$ such that the sum of all $k_i$ is $n$. That is, for each term in the expansion, the exponents of the $x_i$ must add up to n. Also, as with the binomial theorem, quantities of the form $x_0$ that appear are taken to equal 1 (even when $x$ equals zero).
>
> In the case $m = 2,$ this statement reduces to that of the binomial theorem.

Comment: ah, okay. I have never used the multinomial theorem before. Looks rather complicated at first.

Comment: Yes, it can get messing. But it does get the job done!! ;-)

Comment: Let me know if you can make sense of the notation; it would be good to read through the complete linked entry in wikipedia.  Note $\prod x^k$ simply means the product of all the terms in the multinomial

Comment: yes, it helped! Thank you.

Comment: Great, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

There's a theorem called the multinomial theorem. It might be easier to write $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_9$ rather than $a,b,\dots,i$.

Then $$(x_1+\dots+x_9)^{10} = \sum_{\substack{i_1,\dots ,i_9 \\ i_1+\dots  + i_9=10}} \binom{10}{i_1,\dots,i_9} x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}\cdots x_9^{i_9},$$where$$\binom{10}{i_1,\dots,i_9} = \frac{10!}{i_1!\cdots i_9!} .$$

So, the above sum is taken over all $9$-tuples of non-negative integers that add up to $10$.

You can probably prove the multinomial theorem using repeated applications of the binomial theorem, perhaps, but I wouldn't want to try.